# Ask for IPv6 address through IPv4

Tags: ipv6, network-discovery

I am working on a project for discovering IPv6 host over the internet and I have a question. Is there any way that I can send a request to an IPv4 address and return me back their IPv6 address (if it has any) ?

Comment: There is no direct translation from IPv6 to IPv4.  Any translation would only be visible to the NAT device itself assigning the addresses.  As Grawity explains you can prefix an IPv4 address but the resulting address is NOT an actual IPv6 address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- take the IP4 address and do a reverse lookup. This gives you a hostname.
- look for AAAA records for that hostname. That will give you an IP6 address.

Answer (score -2):

It is sort of possible, look at this link:

https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv4toipv6

If you know the ipv4 address already you can convert it from there,
whether you can integrate this into your project I dunno, depends on what your coding in.

Comment: The "conversion" is useless, as it only converts to "IPv4-mapped" address notation (which could be done by just prefixing the IPv4 address with `::ffff:`); the "mapped" addresses still are IPv4 addresses and cannot be used to communicate over an IPv6 network. See [RFC 4291](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.2) and [RFC 4038](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4038#section-4.2) for why they exist at all.

Comment: Hence why I said 'sort of possible'

Comment: @AshKing - If you knew that you should explain that point in detail.